# iterate over dictionaries in module

Tags: python, iteration

I import a module that only contains several dictionaries. How can I iterate over those?
Something along the lines of

```
import moduleX as data
for d in data:
    do stuff with d
```

this obviously does not work as the module is not iterable. is there a way to extract all dicts from module as a collection and iterate through that collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer:

```
import moduleX as data

for k, v in data.__dict__.iteritems():
    if isinstance(v, dict) and not k.startswith('_'):
        # do something
        pass
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am running this on 3.x. Iteritems() seems to have fallen out of that one

Comment: @user1734278 Use `.items()` on Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
for k,v in data.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(v,dict) and k not in __builtins__:
        pass
```

Comment: works as well, but I am a bit confused by the output as I also get e.g. __builtins__ as output. Would have expected to only get dicts. I may misunderstand what python is doing here or this command seems a bit misleading

Comment: you can use k not in __builtins__ to filter those out

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cent solution:

```
>>> for item in dir(data):
...     print item
...     if eval('type(t.'+item+')') is dict: print item, "is a dict"
...
```

or better:

```
>>> for item in dir(data):
...     if eval('isinstance(data.'+item+', dict)') and not item.startswith('_'): 
            print item , "is a dict"
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oz, that was the 2cents I was looking for. eval('data.'+item) now gives me my object

Comment: @user1734278,  I extended my answer a bit, so it is more readable.

Comment: @Oz123: `eval('isinstance(data.'+item+', dict)') ` is better written `isinstance(getattr(data, item, None), dict)`. `eval` is nearly never the right answer.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor, thanks for the comment, I didn't know you can do that. Why is the `None` in the end necessary ? It works also without it...

Comment: @Oz123: `None` is the default to return if the attribute doesn't exist. Without it, you'd get an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vars(object)`:

```
import the_module_with_dictionaries as my_mod

#Get just names of defined dictionaries
for case in vars(my_mod):
    print(case)

#Get the values in those dictionaries
for case in vars(my_mod).values():
    print(case)

    if isinstance(case, dict):
        print("Yay found a dict")
```